# Encrypt a file in javascript (Phonegap application)

Tags: javascript, encryption, cordova, zip, rsa

I have a mobile app created in phongap (=html+javascript) and I need to encrypt e.g. a zip file using an asymmetric cypher like RSA, so once the file is encrypted it is practically impossible for anyone to get the contents without using private key that is only known to the server that the file will be sent to.

Is something like that possible in javascript? Assuming the app would run only on Android and iOS with HTML5 compatible browsers.

Comment: I'd encrypt the message itself with symmetric authenticated encryption(such as AES-GCM) using a random key and then encrypt that random key with RSA.

Comment: It is a little OT, but it's helpful anyway, so could you please elaborate a little more on the choice of random key symmetric cypher with key enprytion rather than straightoforward asymmetric cyphering?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Javascript cryptography in web browsers is a [flawed approach](http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/). But maybe you can use [Cryptico](http://cryptico.wwwtyro.net/) for your task.